# The right way to create Parallel loop

Tags: c#, nhibernate, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I have written a code to crunch some data on Azure server. The first time that I wrote the code, it was linear For Each loop and would take forever to be finished, I improved the code by using Parallel as it follows :

```
Parallel.ForEach(users, currentUser =>
  {
     int number = myrollup.CountFilmsForUsers(currentUser.UserId,distort,tend).Result;
     lock(myrollup)
      {
        var record = new UserAnalytics();
        { 
          UserId = currentUser.UserId,
          UserFName = currentUser.FirstName,
          UserLName = currentUser.LastName,
         };
        session.SaveOrUpdate(record);
       }
    });
```

This parallel loop does the job in 9 min, however I want to improve this more by using a Producer / Consumer pattern. Any ideas on how to do this with Nhibernate in C#?

Comment: Doing something in parallel then guarding most of the loop's body with a lock doesn't make it very parallel.

Comment: I know that this is not as Parallel as I want because Nhibernate is not thread safe. That is why I want to use the Producer / Consumer pattern to make one thread to just read and one thread to write data to my SQL DB.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=producer+consumer+queue

Comment: I suggest you find an article that explains producer-consumer algorithms with the TPL and .NET in general. That will help you more that having the community produce the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely is not a good idea to share one NHibernate session between multiple threads of execution. Try to use [nhibernate profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to find a bottleneck or switch to `StatelessSession` instead